Role of Automata Theory in Today's Biology
Recently I have been studying some mathematical biology, in particular reading about central dogma of biology, how genes code for proteins. When reading about it, one of the things that fascinated me the most was that the terms "transcription" and "translation" were both coined by John von Neumann when he came up with the idea of self replicating automata which can increase its complexity (I read this in Martin Nowak's book, Evolutionary Dynamics). In his book, Nowak also said that the function of the machine that was described by von Neumann was essentially equivalent to the central dogma of biology, and he came up with it quite a few years before the discovery of DNA, which is just awesome!
So having given the background, my question is this - how exactly is von Neumann's self-replicating automata equivalent to central dogma ? What is the role that automata theory plays in mathematical biology, if any ? If I want to read about automata theory, and in particular about von Neumann's work, can you recommend any resources ? I do not have any background in automata theory, but I am comfortable with abstract math like set theory, logic, group theory etc. Thanks!

https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=automata+and+biology&atb=v309-1&ia=web

@JohnDouma In case you didn't realize, googling these terms was the first thing I did, before approaching this website. I do not know any automata theory for me to understand the relevant research. I was looking for someone who could perhaps explain it to me.

If you don't know automata theory, how would someone explain its role in biology and make it clearer than someone who has already written a paper on it? Maybe your needs would be clearer if you explained what you didn't understand about the results that came up in your Google search.
